# WorkManager cannot inject with hilt in dynamic module

Tags: android-workmanager, dagger-hilt, dynamic-feature-module

When I use WorkManager + Hilt in regular module, the app works well. However, when I use in dynamic module, meeting the below issue

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2320)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2166)
    at androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:95)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:242)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:136)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution from this answer
[Using DelegatingWorkerFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59944063/2286345)

It seems Hilt hasn't supported annotation in dynamic module yet. So I must create the factory and add this to DelegatingWorkerFactory. Register DelegatingWorkerFactory in application.